# Что неверно в конструкции awk?

Tags: bash, awk

Пытаюсь получить последнее вхождения строки в файл. С помощью grep все ок:

```
grep "uid=0" /var/log/auth.log | tail -1
Jun 28 09:16:26 hostname systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user vasyn by (uid=0)
```

Пытаюсь повторить то же самое с помощью awk

```
awk '/uid=0/{falg = 1}; flag' auth.log | tail -1
```

Результата нет. $? Показывает 0

Comment: `$ awk '/uid=0/{print$0}' auth.log | tail -n 1`

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это верное решение.